# go replace a char literal in a string

Tags: string, go

In golang, what's the easiest way to replace a char literal in a string?

Here's the C code, where we replace the whitespace with '3':

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    char input[] = "Look ma no hands";
    printf("Input \"%s\" ", input);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++){
        //printf("input[%d] is %c\n", i, input[i]);
        if ( input[i] == ' ' ){
            input[i] = 3;
        }
    }

    printf(",converted to :%s\n", input);
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
$ ./a.out 
Input "Look ma no hands" ,converted to :Lookmanohands
```

How can we do this in golang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the the nearest of the c example I could make:

```
func main() {
    input := "Look ma no hands"

    var b strings.Builder
    b.Grow(len(input))
    for _, p := range input[:] {
        if p == ' '{
            fmt.Fprintf(&b, "%c", '3')
        }else{
            fmt.Fprintf(&b, "%c", p)
        }
    }
    s := b.String()
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

But as you can see, we can't modify the original string so we are not "replacing" in original string but creating a new string.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/xzzT1EKncwP - I had tried that, however `strings.Replace` expects a string. not a char  literal

Comment: In go lang all strings are constants, you cant just replace a single char in a string, you have to assign a new one.

Comment: @struggling_learner: So use a string? Why is it important that it be a character literal? You can take the character literal and make a string with it, if it is somehow important to start with one character.